# Extracting money sums from a character string

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to extract money amounts from a character string.

My text looks like this:

```
data[4,2]
"Pay $500, $100 damages, $400 gas, $250 fee, $50 fees, and $2.50 late fee, 8 days late"
```

And I'm trying to get it to look like this (to not include the 8):

```
data

Person    Fine1      Fine2     Fine3     Fine4     Fine5    Fine6
4         500        100       400       250       50       2.50
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
str_extract(data[4,2], "(?<=$)(\\d|.){2,7}(?=\\s)")
```

However it produces NA.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
> str_extract_all(string, "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")[[1]]
[1] "500"  "100"  "400"  "250"  "50"   "2.50"
```

Using R base

```
> strsplit(trimws(gsub("[^[:digit:]. ]", "", string)), "\\s+")[[1]]
[1] "500"  "100"  "400"  "250"  "50"   "2.50"
```

If your string has other numbers which are not money amount, just like this example:

```
 string <- "Pay $500 and $2.50 late fee. Pay $200 for 3 cats and buy 3 apples"
```

and you only want to extract prices, then you can use this:

```
> library(stringr)
> library(magrittr)
> string %>% str_extract_all(., "\\$\\s*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") %>%
  unlist %>% 
  gsub("\\$", "", .)
[1] "500"  "2.50" "200"
```

Comment: This is really helpful, except there are other numbers in my text as well. That's why I was trying to use the $ symbol to separate other numbers from the money amounts.

Comment: @AnnaRouw that is not part of your question. Update your question and provide a reproducible example as well as your desired output so we can understand your problem and give you a suitable answer.

Comment: Ok I updated the question, sorry I didn't think about the other numbers initially!